# Flutter: Allow app execution when phone is locked

Tags: android, flutter

Is there a way to allow my application to be run even if the phone is locked? I'm using [TapTap](https://github.com/KieronQuinn/TapTap/releases) to launch it but it won't work unless I unlock the phone. (This is an application that toggles between normal, vibrate and silent mode).